# GooglePlus login: Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri

Tags: angular, ionic2, google-plus, google-plus-signin

I am using Ionic2/Cordova to log into an app using `Facebook` and `Google`.

When I log into the app using `Facebook`, it works perfectly.

```
  loginFacebookCordova(): void {
    Facebook.login(['public_profile', 'email']).then(facebookData => {
      let cred: firebase.auth.AuthCredential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(facebookData.authResponse.accessToken);
      firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(cred).then((data: FirebaseAuthState) => {
        this.signIn(data, AuthProviders.Facebook);
      });
    }, error => {
      this.loading.dismiss();
      console.error('loginFacebook: ' + error);
      this.doAlert('loginFacebook: ' + error.message);
    });
  }
```

However, when I try `Google` with the following, it just hangs:

```
  loginGoogleCordova(): void {
    GooglePlus.login(['public_profile', 'email']).then(googleData => {
      alert('logged in!');
      let cred: firebase.auth.AuthCredential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(googleData.authResponse.accessToken);
      firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(cred).then((data: FirebaseAuthState) => {
        this.signIn(data, AuthProviders.Google);
      });
    }, error => {
      this.loading.dismiss();
      console.error('loginGoogle: ' + error);
      this.doAlert('loginGoogle: ' + error.message);
    });
  }
```

`'logged in!'` does not get alerted.

Does anyone have any ideas what I am doing incorrectly?

More info:

I am using `"ionic-native": "2.2.11"`.

**UPDATE**

Thank you for the comment below. I try the following:

```
  loginGoogleCordova(): void {
    GooglePlus.login({
      'webClientId': 'mywebclientid.apps.googleusercontent.com',
      'offline': true
    }).then(googleData => {
      if (!firebase.auth().currentUser) {
        firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(googleData.idToken))
          .then((success: FirebaseAuthState) => {
            this.doAlert("signInWithCredential successful " + JSON.stringify(success));
            this.signIn(success, AuthProviders.Google);
          })
          .catch((gplusErr) => {
            console.error('GooglePlus failed ' + gplusErr);
            this.doAlert("GooglePlus failed " + JSON.stringify(gplusErr))
          });
      }
    }, error => {
      this.loading.dismiss();
      console.error('loginGoogle: ' + error);
      this.doAlert('loginGoogle: ' + error.message);
    });
  }
```

Which looks like it makes progress, because it now accesses the Google api. But I get the following:

> Invalid parameter for redirect uri: Invalid Scheme:
>   mywebclientid.apps.googleusercontent.com

[image]

But when I check my `Web client ID` in the Firebase `Authentication` -> `Sign-in Method`, this is the `Web client ID`.

[image]

Also, when I installed the plugin, I ran:

```
$ ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-googleplus --variable REVERSED_CLIENT_ID=mywebclientid.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

As you can see, it is also in the Xcode's `plist` file:

[image]

**UPDATE**

I did notice that when looking at my [Google APIs](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials), that the `CLIENT ID` is created for `Web client`:

[image]

I that the problem? Should I create one `CLIENT ID` for `iOS` and another for `Android`?

[image]

Then have `if statements`:

```
if iOS
  use iOS client id
if Android
  use Android Client id
```

But as you can see from [here](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus/blob/master/demo/ionic2/pages/home/home.ts), it uses: `'webClientId': 'USE-YOURS-HERE!!!!!.apps.googleusercontent.com'`

Also, when the [plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/google-plus/) is installed, it is installed with:

```
$ ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-googleplus --variable REVERSED_CLIENT_ID=myreversedclientid
```

So what CLIENT ID do you user here?

As a result, I am a little confused, and any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus/tree/master/demo/ionic2

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look

Comment: Thanks Suraj. It looks like your suggestion helps, but I am having a problem with my CLIENT ID. Please see above for more details.

Comment: try setting the right values in https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials for Authorized JavaScript origins and Authorized redurect uri (which I guess is missing in your case)

Comment: Hi user1928596, thanks for the reply. Do I need to set up different CLIENT IDs for each platform (iOS, Android & Web)? Please see my last UPDATE above, I am a little confused.

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: as you can see here: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient you can create an client_id for mobile use, which normally uses different OAuth flows. but since you are using firebase all of that shouldn't matter.
IMPORANT: do not put your ClientSecret in the mobile app, if you want authentication use OpenidConnect (firebase normaly does that for you)

Comment: Thanks for the tip regarding the ClientSecret.  I am still confused about what I need to do with the CLIENT ID. i.e. I am not sure what type of CLIENT ID to create that will work for iOS, Android and Web.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137464/discussion-between-user1928596-and-richard).

Comment: I need to authenticate in the client, because I plan to have an Ionic Client and only a Firebase Database.

Comment: Was there any progress on this, could you quite possibly answer with your solution?